# Zohar and Shabbos Yoma D’Nishmasa

Tags: shabbat, sources-mekorot, soul, zohar

The Zohar calls Shabbos Yoma D’Nishmasa, because it is the day of the soul, not the day of the body.

Do anyone know where the source for this zohar is located?

Comment: How do you the Zohar calls Shabbos that?

Answer (score 5):

[*Vayakheil* 205a](http://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%96%D7%94%D7%A8_%D7%97%D7%9C%D7%A7_%D7%91_%D7%A8%D7%94_%D7%90):

> האי יומא יומא דנשמתין איהו ולאו יומא דגופא

English:

> This day is a day of souls and not a day of the body.